# Show html depending on the current route params

Tags: angular

In my component I want to show a text depending on the current route params, in the template I did as following :

```
<h1 *ngIf="mode === 'edit'">Modifier</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="mode === 'add'">Ajouter</h1>
```

And in ngOnInit function I have this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = +params['id'];
    this.currentMode = params['mode'];
})
```

But when I access my component the element is always hidden despite that the `currentMode` was set.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Then you should also check `currentMode` in your template. Currently you are checking `mode`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use currentMode instead of just mode? `*ngIf="currentMode === 'edit'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `param` name in the template, use the variable name, i.e `this.currentMode`.

```
<h1 *ngIf="currentMode === 'edit'">Modifier</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="currentMode === 'add'">Ajouter</h1>
```

Assumption here is you are getting the value from param in the variable `this.currentMode`, I'd test that out just by printing it beside the tag like:

```
{{currentMode}}
```